# Adding together elements contained in two lists

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to add elements of two lists together e.g. listing all integers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5. The sum of these multiples should be 23 (3+5+6+9) but I keep getting 18. I have only just starting programming and learning python. Here's my code:

```
for i in range (1,10):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print(i)
for x in range (1,10):
    if x % 5 ==0:
        print(x)
sum_multiples=i+x
print(sum_multiples)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, let me address your problem. When you add variable `i` and variable `x`, they are both value of 9. This is because after the loop their value is 9, and because you are adding the values after the loop, you are adding `9 + 9`.

You can fix this by making a variable outside the loop and adding the number to the variable. My code would be:

```
total = 0
for i in range (1,10):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print(i)
        total = total + i
for x in range (1,10):
    if x % 5 ==0:
        print(x)
        total = total + x

print(total)
```

(this is just based off what you were doing, I would probably condense it into one loop)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do:

```
3 + 6 + 9 + 5 = 23
```

What you are doing:

```
9 + 9 = 18
```

This is what you want:

```
l1 = [x for x in range(1, 10) if x % 3 == 0]
l2 = [x for x in range(1, 10) if x % 5 == 0]
print(sum(l1) + sum(l2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like this:

```
sum_multiples = 0
for i in range(1, 10):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        sum_multiples += i
print(sum_multiples)
```

If you prefer a one line solution:

```
print(sum(i for i in range(1, 10) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0))
```